# Resize a textarea on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm using the `autosize` plugin (but wouldn't mind alternatives) and I need to resize the `textarea` I have on its load, and it should also automatically resize as you type (like what `autosize.js` allows you to do).

My question is, does `autosize` come with this option out of the box? I didn't find such info on its webpage and I tried both `$(el).trigger('autosize.resize')` and `autosize.update($(el))` after my text areas are loaded and neither worked.

Also, my textareas are original hidden, which will be toggled show with a CSS class. I wonder if that's hindering the process.

Any ideas is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `display: none` you can't calculate anything because the height & width of the textarea is 0x0px.

You must update the size after textarea has been shown. 
Edit : or toggle it shown first then apply autosize.

Comment: Yeah but using `display:none` is the easiest for me to show/hide different UI components without extra CSS. Any workaround here?

Comment: Do your `$(el).trigger('autosize.resize')` or `autosize.update($(el))` when you show your textarea ?

Comment: I didn't, just tried toggle it shown first then apply autosize and it works like a charm, thank you! Could you update your answer a little so I can take it as the correct answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried different plugins and even wrote a plugin myself but none of them were good. I ended up using a div with `contenteditable="true"`

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I'll try that if no solutions can be found for text area, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you use CSS to size the `textarea` appropriately on initial load, and then let the `autosize` script handle resizing the `textarea` as the content is changed?

Comment: You mean make it transparent, or `visibility-hidden: true`?

Comment: You said 'I need to resize the textarea I have on its load', so I was thinking you could specify the `min-height` or `height` in CSS to control the initial size of the `textarea`.